# matplotlib save to pdf and have subplots as embedded vector images

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib

I'd like to generate a summary PDF every time I run a particular scientific model, where I will want to inspect the graphs of every stage of the model.

So, every model run generates a 2-page PDF, each page having 11 or 12 subplots and some summary text.

I have code that does a minimum working example of this, but when the PDF is generated,  I can select the text of individual axis labels, or individual characters in the title?

What i have now: (blue background is highlighted)

[image: model-selecting]

How can i instead generate subplots so that i can select the *entire subplot* as an image that I can, e.g., copy out of the PDF. (blue background also highlighted)

[image]

Should I effectively save many SVGs, one per subplot, and them embed them as PNGs in the PDF ?

```
with PdfPages(path.join(outputPath, fileName)) as pdf:
        for i in range(len(periphery)):

            figure = plt.figure(1, (8.5, 11), dpi=300)
            gs = gridspec.GridSpec(6, 4)
            periph = periphery[i]
            stimulus = periph[p.Stimulus]
            pointCount = len(stimulus)
            time = np.linspace(0, pointCount / conf.Fs, num=pointCount)

            # plot stimulus
            stimt = plt.subplot(gs[0, :-3])
            stimt.plot(time, stimulus, lw=2)
            stimt.set_xlabel("Time, s")
            stimt.set_ylabel("Amplitude ")
            stimt.set_title("Stimulus")
            stimf = plt.subplot(gs[1, 3:-1])


            pdf.savefig(figure)
```

Comment: Yes. SVG is drawn into the pdf as lines and text and such and is not an image the viewer.

Comment: How does matplotlib's PDF backend handle image resizing?  Maybe a better way to go would be to generate PNGs from SVG at high DPI and large native resolution, then fit them into a PDF but embed the full resolution image..